# Get TableA id where TableB id is equal to TableA column which has a string

Tags: mysql

I have two tables TableA and TableB.

TableA:

```
id | users        |
-------------------
1  | ["2","5","4"]|
2  | NULL         |
3  | ["5"]        |
```

TableB

```
id | Name |
-----------
2  | Jane |
3  | Joe  |
4  | John |
5  | Jack |
```

How can I get a result to show the TableA id where TableB id is in TableA Users?

- So for Jane = 1
- for Joe = Null
- for John = 1
- and Jack = 1,3

Comment: Does your `users` column really contain a string `["2","5","4"]` ?

Comment: Not sure what to call it, but the result of JSON_ENCODE

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here :-( . json_encode makes this unnecessarily complicated

Comment: Which other way do you prefer to store multiple ids for a specific row?

Comment: A link or cross reference table

Comment: See normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.Name,
       COALESCE(a.id, 'NA') AS a_id
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.users, '[', ''), ']', ''), '"', '')) > 0
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: It certainly looks promising. Just trying to fix an "in on clause is ambiguous" error.

Comment: Thank you, you are a genius! I accidently missed the a. in a.users. I certainly learned something new.

Comment: @user3256635 Keep in mind I'm assuming that your JSON data will always be single level arrays as you have shown.  If nested data or something else, you might need a slightly different solution.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen, if i was to show only the id of TableA for the id of John, where would I be adding the _where_ clause?

Comment: Then add `WHERE b.Name = 'John'` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table (i) of integers (0-9) (also i)...

I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution, but just for fun...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_b;

CREATE TABLE table_a
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,users VARCHAR(100) NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
(1,'["2","5","4"]'),
(2,NULL),
(3,'["5"]');

CREATE TABLE table_b
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES
(2,'Jane'),
(3,'Joe'),
(4,'John'),
(5,'Jack');

SELECT b.name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(a.id ORDER BY a.id+0) ids
  FROM table_b b
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT a.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                       REPLACE(
                         REPLACE(
                           REPLACE(a.users,'"','')
                           ,'[','')
                           ,']','')                       
                       ,',',i.i+1)
                       ,',',-1)
                       x 
                  FROM 
                 table_a a,ints i
      ) a
     ON a.x = b.id
  GROUP
     BY name;

 +------+------+
 | name | ids  |
 +------+------+
 | Jack | 1,3  |
 | Jane | 1    |
 | Joe  | NULL |
 | John | 1    |
 +------+------+
```